# Why does the browser loads a larger srcset image for a fixed-width image using the sizes attribute?

Tags: html, image, next.js, frontend, nextjs-image

I have an image containing both `sizes` and `srcset` (dynamically generated by Next.js). The image will have a fixed width on certain resolutions, which I specified in the `sizes` attribute for those resolutions. However, whenever I test this, the browser loads the largest possible image for that case, even though the displayed image is much, much smaller.

#### Full image source (URLs simplified):

```
<img
  fetchpriority="high"
  width="615"
  height="615"
  decoding="async"
  sizes="(max-width: 768px) 768w, (max-width: 1280px) 295w, (max-width: 1600px) 486w, 615w"
  srcset="1.png 16w, 2.png 32w, 3.png 48w, 4.png 64w, 5.png 96w, 6.png 128w, 7.png 256w, 8.png 384w, 9.png 768w, 10.png 1280w, 11.png 1600w"
  src="11.png"
>
```

When I'm on a window size wider than 1600px, I expected it to load image `9.png` as it is resized to be 768px wide, and is closer to the last size of 615w, last in the sizes attribute. That doesn't happen, as the browser loads the largest `11.png` image that is 1600px wide. I'm testing on Chrome, and PageSpeed has the same behavior.

Comment: The sizes attribute is invalid. It should use a px, em or vw as size unit, not w.

Comment: @Salketer I got mixed with the srcset and used w for sizes as well. Silly me. Thanks!